# Getting "Expected expression" error when declaring a dictionary in Swift 3, Xcode 8

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary

Working through "Cocoa Programming For OS X", and I am getting an error when declaring a dictionary using Swift 3.0 in Xcode 8 Version 8.0 (8A218a). I think my syntax is correct?

```
var dictionaryCapitalsByCountry: Dictionary [String: String]()
```

Shows up in playground with error, "Expected expression"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dictionaryCapitalsByCountry: Dictionary<String, String> = Dictionary<String, String>()
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply mistyped dictionary initialization
should be:
[image]